# How to create streams in Apache Storm based on Oracle or MySQL table polling?

Tags: apache-storm

I need to polling a table and create a tuple for each row for streaming in Apache Storm.

Where could I find a example ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, it does't have much to do with storm. This is a database related question.

Since you have no info about the database to use, the table structure and so on, I would drop a rough steps:

Supposing the table has a `last-updated-timestamp` or an increment ID, using it as a marker to pull data. take ID for example.

1) execute sql `select * from myyable where id > ${last retrived id} order by id limit 100` every 100ms. ${last retrived id} will be -1 for initial.

2) iterate the result sets and send out tuples

3) update ${last retrived id} with the last record's id.

(and please notice that if using the last updated timestamp, there would be some difference because different record can have the same last update timestamp)

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

We have a Storm MySql Spout that caters to your requirements. It tails the bin logs to generate the tuples.

https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/storm-mysql

You can use the table filters to actually listen to bin log events of only the table you are interested in. So whenever a Insert/Delete/Update is done on the table it generates a tuple.

The spout also gives you "at least once/at most once" guarantees. Since it stores the bin log offsets in Zookeeper, in the event of a crash it can recover from where it last was. There is no need for any polling.

Disclaimer: Author of the aforementioned spout